# Discrete Math Question: Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

I am having lots of trouble answering this question:

Define a sequence recursively as follows. $x_1 = 1$ and for $n ∈ N, x_{n+1} = \sqrt{(x_n)^2 + 1/(x_n)^2}$

Prove using mathematical induction that for all n ∈ N, $ 1 ≤ x_n ≤\sqrt{n}$

In order to solve this question, I feel you need to find a closed formula for this recursive sequence, but I cannot find that formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base Case, clear.

Induction Hypothesis: Assume that $1 \leq x_n \leq \sqrt{n}$ for all $n \leq m$.

Induction step: Consider $x_m$. We note that $$x_m = \sqrt{(x_{m-1})^2 + \frac{1}{(x_{m-1})^2}}\leq \sqrt{(x_{m-1})^2 + 1} \leq \sqrt{(\sqrt{m-1})^2 +1} = \sqrt{m }$$

The "$ 1 \leq$" portion is easier and is left to you to figure out. Notice that we did not need to find a closed form formula.

Comment: Thankyou very much sir. But I don't understand how you plugged 'n' back in during your inequalities. Can you please elaborate on that step?

Comment: @user4289755: oops! I messed up. I have corrected the proof. Notice that this step is where we have used our induction hypothesis.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! This makes perfect sense.

Comment: @KyleGannon: Why don't you assume solely that $1\le x_n\le n$ for some $n\ge1$ and prove that $1\le x_{n+1}\le\sqrt{n+1}$ ? Strong induction is not necessary here.

Comment: @Adren: Strong induction isn't "necessary" here, but strong and weak induction are equivalent. I hadn't proved the statement before writing my solution and I have always been in the habit of writing my proofs using strong induction. It's just personal taste.